# Collecting two values from a DataFrame, and using them as parameters for a case class; looking for less verbose solution

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've got some data in spark, `result: DataFrame = ...`, where two integer columns are of interest; `week` and `year`. The values of these columns are identical for all rows.

I want to extract these two integer values, and pass them as parameters to create a `WeekYear`:

```
case class WeekYear(week: Int, year: Int)
```

Below is my current solution, but I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way to do this. How can this be done without the intermediate step of creating `temp`?

```
val temp = result
  .select("week", "year")
  .first
  .toSeq
  .map(_.toString.toInt)

val resultWeekYear = WeekYear(temp(0), temp(1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to utilize a `case class` with dataframes is to allow spark to convert it to a dataset with the `.as()` method. As long as your case class has attributes which match all of the column names, it should work very easily.

```
case class WeekYear(week: Int, year: Int)
val df = spark.createDataset(Seq((1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3))).toDF("week", "year")
val ds = df.as[WeekYear]
ds.show()
```

Which provides a `Dataset[WeekYear]` that looks like this:

```
+----+----+
|week|year|
+----+----+
|   1|   1|
|   2|   2|
|   3|   3|
+----+----+
```

You can utilize some more complicated nested classes, but you have to start working with [`Encoders`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoder.html) for that, so that spark knows how to convert back and forth.

Spark does some implicit conversions, so `ds` may still *look* like a `Dataframe`, but it is actually a strongly typed `Dataset[WeekYear]`, instead of a `Dataset[Row]` that has arbitrary columns. You operate on it similarly to an `RDD`. Then just grab the `.first()` one of those and you'll already have the type you need.

```
val resultWeekYear = ds.first
```